# Not able to upload IPA to MS App Center for distribution

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-app-center

I am not able to upload the IPA file onto AppCenter to distribute it. It is giving me the following error:

```
Release:
Error: Missing required params from body: version, build_version, unique_identifier, minimum_os_version, Service id: b5610a15-e72f-47b0-a211-b235e7ce6419
```

Where would I enter these values? Apart from unique_identifier, I have the others specified in Xcode already:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These missing parameters are likely due to the fact that your IPA file isn't properly signed (Developer/Enterprise for testing or AppStore for distribution).

We ran into this same issue when we were having some problems with code signing and once we got those issues resolved all the correct information was available for AppCenter to parse when we performed the upload.

You can test out your signing process by doing an `Archive` from the Product menu, and then in Window > Archive Manager you can view the output file and choose `Distribute app` and it should give you the option to select a Developer/AdHoc/Enterprise or App Store certificate to sign the application, once the IPA is generated you should be able to successfully upload it to AppCenter.